# very noisy fan on my hp pavilion dm4 beats edition

Tags: fan, hp-pavilion, noise, speedfan

As the title shows, the fan is very noisy. I don't remember since when but it's always running at its high speed and it's disturbing when i am in class.

I tried to clean the fan, upgrade BIOS, speedfan, stilll nothing!

Answer (score 1):

It's an HP DM4 design flaw and you can't do anything apart from buying another laptop and not the same one! I've had HP Pavilion DM4 3002AE Beats Edition and the fan was making terrible noise and vibrated a lot. I've replaced 3 brand new CPU Fan & heatsink assemblies as you can't just replace the fan and all of them had exactly the same problem. I've tried to apply a grease to the fan itself which worked for a couple of weeks and then noise was back. Taking that laptop apart every time was such a time waste. It was one of the most annoying and irritating laptops I've ever had. Avoid it at any cost.

Comment: a very useful answer

Answer (score 0):

How did you clean your fan? By disassembling your laptop or with just air from outside? Once I had a laptop with a very noisy fan and was still noisy after cleaning the whole computer from inside and outside. The solution was to put some motor oil at the fan. And then it was fine.

Comment: oh dear lord! I don't want to re-open it again! such a killing task, the laptop is one year old! are you serious about oil?
 any other suggestions maybe?:(

Comment: yeah i'm serious. Google "oiling pc fan" and you can see many guys to use this method :)

Answer (score 0):

Just seeing this old thread. Hopefully all of your problesm are resolved by now, but...just in case.

Click on your battery icon > more power options --> power saver --> change plan settings --> change advanced power settings --> (expand) processor power management --> maximum processor state > set this to 30 %

Comment: This just configures the fan not to run at full speed which will mean he won't get the best performance out of his processor when its warm.